# return false when answer is correct,how can fix the code in php?

Tags: php

How can make when the answer be correct a message appears that the answer is correct??
                                                                                            This is my attempt>I try to make (if) but it is return false when the answer is correct>> How can fix this problem
                                                                                                     Please Help!!!

```html
<table dir="rtl"style="margin-right: 10px;" id="rounded-corner" summary="2007 Major IT Companies' Profit" style="margin-left:150px;">
    <thead>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
 
<?php

$query_run=mysql_query("select * from questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_run))
        {
         $question = $row['question']; 
   $ans = $row['ans'];
   $anstwo = $row['anstwo'];
   $correct_ans = $row['correct_ans'];

?>

    <tr> 
         <th  colspan="3"width="211" class="rounded" scope="col">السؤال</th>          
   </tr>         
  <tr>
    <?php
        
echo"<tr><td> <img src=question/$question width=100 hieght=100></td></tr>";
echo"<tr><td><label>
  <input type=\"radio\" name=\"fb\" value=\"small\" /><img src=question/$ans width=100 hieght=100></label></td><td><label>
  <input type=\"radio\" name=\"fb\" value=\"small\" /><img src=question/$anstwo width=100 hieght=100></label></td><td><label>
  <input type=\"radio\" name=\"fb\" value=\"$correct_ans\" /><img src=question/$correct_ans width=100 hieght=100></label></td</tr><br>";
 
  ?>  
</tr>
<?php
 }
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
   $value = $_POST;

    if ($value == "$correct_ans")
        echo "THAT ANSWER IS CORRECT";
    else
        echo "THAT ANSWER IS WRONG!";}
 ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($value == "$correct_ans")
        echo "THAT ANSWER IS CORRECT";
    else
        echo "THAT ANSWER IS WRONG!";}
```

should be

```
if ($value == $correct_ans)
{
        echo "THAT ANSWER IS CORRECT";
}else
{
       echo "THAT ANSWER IS WRONG!";
}
```

"$correct_ans" as posted by you is a string not a variable.

Comment: Can you var_dump($value) and see what it returns?